# How to add local storage space to nextcloud/owncloud data pool without using the external storage app?

Tags: server, owncloud-server, online-storage, nextcloud

I'm using Nextcloud on Digital Ocean, and I've added a 100GB volume to the droplet in question.

However, the step that I'm having some trouble quite figuring out is how to get Nexcloud to use the extra space, without using the external storage app (which creates a folder for the device, rather than simply using it as part of the pool of available space).

While I could just use this option, I'd rather not if I don't have to.

How would I configure Nextcloud to use this extra storage as if it were part of the data folder?

P.S. *before anyone asks, I've asked on the Nextcloud forum, but quite honestly I got tired of going in circles, as often happens on forums* :).

Comment: Check out this how-to. It talks you through moving the OC or NC data folder onto another drive. https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=7118